# How to check permission in flag?

Tags: javascript

A user has permission 12

12 = `1100`

8 = `1000` = create
4 = `0100` = read
2 = `0010` = update
1 = `0001` = delete

How to check whether this user has create permission?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You use the [bitwise AND operator (`&`)](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.10), like this:

```
if ((flag & 0x08) == 0x08) {
    // They have it
}
```

(0x08 hex = 1000 binary = 8 decimal.)

`&` takes the operands and gives back a value containing only the bits that are set in **both** of the operands (after converting the operands to standard 2's complement 32-bit integers). So `0x0C & 0x08` is `0x08` because the `0x08` bit is set in both operands, but (say) `0x07 & 0x08` is `0x00` because one of the operands *doesn't* have the bit set.

If you're checking for a value that you **know** contains only one bit (like `0x08`), you don't actually need the `== 0x08` part, this is fine:

```
if (flag & 0x08) {
    // They have it
}
```

**But** if you ever have masks you need to check with multiple bits, like `0x0A`, you need the `==` because otherwise the result will be truthy for `0x08` or `0x02` as well as for `0x0A`. So using the pattern `(thingToTest & flagToTestFor) == flagToTestFor` is a good habit to be in.

You don't have to use hex, but I find it handy when working with bits (since JavaScript doesn't have a literal binary notation). Or you might consider some "constants" (which can really be constants in ES6, but for now we'll stick with ES5) that you declare at the beginning of your code:

```
var CREATE_FLAG = parseInt("1000", 2);
var READ_FLAG   = parseInt("0100", 2);
var UPDATE_FLAG = parseInt("0010", 2);
var DELETE_FLAG = parseInt("0001", 2);
```

...and then you can do `if ((flag & CREATE_FLAG) == CREATE_FLAG)`.